# Reat Native & RTK Query - Call an other endpoint when request is success

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, rtk-query

I am new in Redux & RTK Query and I do not understand how I can fetch data from another endpoint when response of another endpoint is succeed.

I created an API like that:

```js
import { Config } from '@/Config'
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: Config.API_URL })

const baseQueryWithInterceptor = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)

  if (result.error && result.error.status === 401) {
    // Deal with unauthorised
  }
  return result
}

export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithInterceptor,
  endpoints: () => ({}),
})
```

I have a modules for each resource, example:

```js
// /modules/matches

import { api } from '../../api'
import { fetchMatches } from '@/Services/modules/matches/fetchMatches'

export const matchApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: build => ({
    fetchMatches: fetchMatches(build),
  }),
  overrideExisting: false,
})

export const { useFetchMatchesQuery } = matchApi


// /modules/matches/fetchMatches

export const fetchMatches = build => {
  return build.query({
    query: type => ({ url: `matches/${type}` })
  })
}
```

So, in my component I am calling it with:

```js
const { data: matches, error, isLoading } = useFetchMatchesQuery('explorer')
```

Now, what i need to do when `useFetchMatchesQuery` is succeed is:

1. Create an array with all match's id from `useFetchMatchesQuery` response data
2. Call an other query to fetch an other data with `matchsIds` in params
3. Use response in the same component who render `matches` data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main option here is to have a second `useSomeOtherQuery()` hook in the same component, but "skip" that query until the first query is complete. This can be done be either passing `{skip: false}` as an option, or the `skipToken` variable as the query argument:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i used:

```js
// /Containers/MyContainer

const [matchesIds, setMatchesIds] = useState([])

const {
    data: matches,
    error: matchesError,
    isLoading: matchesIsLoading,
  } = useFetchMatchesQuery('explorer')

  const {
    data: winnerMarkets,
    error: winnerMarketsError,
    isLoading: winnerMarketsIsLoading,
  } = useFetchWinnerMarketsQuery(matchesIds, { skip: matchesIds.length === 0 })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (matches) {
      const mIds = []
      matches.map(match => {
         mIds.push(match.id)
      })
      setMatchesIds(mIds)
    }
  }, [matches])
```

Comment: Thanks @markerikson :)